# How to remove project external dependecy on project build

Tags: .net, visual-studio, build, build-automation

To debug and analyze performance in our project we use rhino entity profiler.
It requires to add rhino profiler dll as project reference.

As we need this feature only in debug it would be nice to completly remove this reference on publishing.

It would be great if there were something like:

```
#if DEBUG
    <some dll reference />
#endif
```

Is there are any relativly simple solution to achive this?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use any the code, you can safely remove the dependency for a release build.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by manually editing your project file as outlined below, but I tend to shy away from manually modifying my project files if at all possible.  It can become a nightmare to maintain if you are having to make this change across multiple projects or add new projects that need these same settings.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <!--put any references you want to just show up in debug mode in here -->
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <Reference Include="System" />
  </ItemGroup>
```